# Is OAuth2 Authorization header with "Bearer [access_token]" standard?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

Question regarding the OAuth2 Authorization header,

Some sites use `Authorization: Bearer [access_token]`

but some sites use `Authorization: OAuth [access_token]`.

So is both of them a valid oauth2 spec based on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Authorization: Bearer [access_token]` is defined in [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750), but `Authorization: OAuth [access_token]` is not.

You can find `Authorization: OAuth ...` in [RFC 5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) (The OAuth 1.0 Protocol). Note that RFC 5849 is obsoleted.